# basic arrays and functions in C - selftaught

Tags: c

I'm very new to the C programming language and Stack Exchange. I'm learning on my own and have recently refined a rudimentary skill set in Matlab. I'm attempting to mess around with arrays in the following C code sample, which I hope I have adequately explained throughout. When I compile the code, however, I'm immediately met with a segmentation fault. I'm not sure where I've hit my iceberg, and I'm looking for a solution so I can learn by good example.

```
/* colAdd takes a 4,4 array 'A' and adds columns 'C1' and 'C2', 
   placing the result in column 'C1'. Prints  matrix 'A'. 
   Void function as result is only printed, not returned.
   Main tests colAdd with simple 4,4 array */

#include <stdio.h>

// Function colAdd is declared
void colAdd(int A[4][4], int C1, int C2);

int main()
{
    // Function colAdd is initialised
    int A[4][4] = {{1,2,3,4},{5,6,7,8},{9,10,11,12},{13,14,15,16}}; 
    colAdd(A,1,3);
}

void colAdd(int A[4][4], int C1, int C2)
{
    int j = 0; int i; int arr1[4]; int arr2[4]; int arr3[4];

    // The following takes column C1 of A and places the result in arr1
    for(i = (C1 - 1); i = (C1 + 11); i + 4) {
    arr1[j] = A[C1][i];
    j = j + 1;
    }
    j = 0;

    // The following takes column C2 of A and places the result in arr2
    for(i = (C2 - 1); i = (C2 + 11); i + 4) {
    arr2[j] = A[C2][i];
    j = j + 1;
    }

    // The following takes the addition of arr1 and arr2 and places the result in arr3
    for(i = 0; i = 3; i++) {
    arr3[i] = arr2[i] + arr1[i];
    }
    j = 0;

    // The following replaces column C1 of array A with arr3
    for(i = (C1 - 1); i = (C1 + 11); i + 4) {
    A[C1][i] = arr3[j];
    j = j + 1;
    }

    //Finally, the resultant array A is printed
    const int rows = 4; 
    const int cols = 4; 
    int k; int l;
    for(k = 0; k < rows; k++) {
        for(l = 0; l < cols; l++) {
        printf("ans[%d, %d] = %d \n", k, l, A[k][l]);
        }
    }
}
```

Any advice would be much appreciated. Thank you all kindly.

Comment: Double check that your loops are going to iterate over the correct indexes for your valid set of inputs. Looks like you will attempt to index outside our array in multiple places. Also, it looks like you want '==' rather than '='.

Comment: Do you loops break ever? Check those loop conditions: `i = (C1 + 11)`, `i = (C2 + 11)`, `i = 3` etc.

Comment: `for(i = (C1 - 1); i = (C1 + 11); i + 4) {` : This is an infinite loop. infinite  do `j = j + 1;` then `arr1[j]` out of bounds

Comment: And how do you access A[C1][i] when i is C1 + 11? A is only 4x4.

Comment: My understanding was that "for(i = (C1 - 1); i = (C1 + 11); i + 4)" was equatable to "for i = C1-1: 4 : C1+11' based on prior MATLAB experience. Perhaps this is not the case?

Comment: I suggest you to first study about 2 dimensional arrays.As your code has lots of bugs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have:

```
// The following takes column C1 of A and places the result in arr1
for(i = (C1 - 1); i = (C1 + 11); i + 4) {
   arr1[j] = A[C1][i];
   j = j + 1;
}
```

Your code doesn't do what your comment says it should. Your understanding of `for` statement is not quite right.

Use:

```
for(i = 0;  // This is executed only once.
    i < 4;  // This is executed for every iteration of the loop.
            // The loop is terminated if this statement is false.
    ++i)    // This is executed for every iteration after the
            // statements of the loop are executed. 
{
   arr1[i] = A[i][C1];
}
```

Hopefully this gives you enough to fix the rest of the function.

Comment: I've had a massive light-bulb moment on the basis of both your and AzNjoE's answers. There's much about C I'm still learning, but this has cleared up an awful deal concerning both arrays and loops in C. I suspect I'm going to have a lot of fun with this. Thank you both.

Comment: @Boya, glad I was able to help.

Comment: @RSahu arr1[i]=A[C1][i].I think this should be arr1[i]=A[i][C1] since Boya wants to add the columns.

Answer (score 0):

Your array 'A' is a 4x4 2D array, but you access your array's 2nd index using 'i', which will eventually be 12 in the first two loops in your function colAdd(). This will cause an index out of bounds error (or segmentation fault).

I'm guessing 'i' should be 'j' when indexing through the 2D array.

Also you should use "==" for the terminating condition in your for loop, instead of "=" which is assignment. Also how you increment through the loop 'i + 4', won't change 'i', you need a "+=" or do "i = i + 4".

Comment: I aggree with this answer, besides you should also deal with pointers as a better praxis to deal with memory. Anyway using Matlab or Octave will always be better if you're just trying to compute some data or even using it to learn machine learning algorithms, etc.

Comment: A good practice since you are learning is to debug and use breakpoints and print some results as well to check what's going on within your program. Also writing and checking the loop is always better than just copying a snippet. Notice the difference as pointed by AzNjoE between '==' and '=' and the correct syntaxis to perform the increment of 'i'. Have fun coding!